# c# Overriding + operator for dictionary to provide easy default values

Tags: c#, dictionary, overriding

I have a dictionary of

```
IDictionary<TKey, long> dictionary;
```

Instead of using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=net-6.0 to add values to the list like so:

```
dictionary[key] = dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(key) + value;
```

I would like to just do:

```
dictionary[key] += value;
```

Is there a way to override or subclass or wrap dictionary to do this correctly?

Comment: What exactly *are* you trying to do? Do you want to accumulate the value, or do you want to add the value to the dictionary only if it's not there? If you do `dictionary[key] += value;` a second time, do you want it to replace the value or add to what's already there?

Comment: @madreflection Add to the value if it is there.  If it is not there, set the value (or add it to the default value, which is 0).

Comment: And if it already exists, what should it do?

Comment: Add to the current value that is there.  Same as this does: dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(key) + value;

Comment: Yes, works fine:
            Dictionary<string, long> count = new Dictionary<string, long>();
            count["a"] = count.GetValueOrDefault("a") + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(count["a"]);
Prints 1

Comment: You can't overload operators for types you don't control, so you're not going to get `+=` to do what you want. Write an extension method and give it a meaningful name. And even if you had control over the type, you can't overload `+=`. You would have to redefine the indexer to return the default value if the item doesn't exist.